# database Image not getting displayed asp.net

Tags: asp.net

trying to display an image from database in an image control... third day...no luck so far...

Displaybutton on Employee.aspx

```
 Protected Sub DisplayButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DisplayButton.Click

    bind()
    GridView1.Visible = "True"
    If EmployeeIDTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter EmployeeID!")
    Else
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/HttpHandler.ashx?EmployeeID=" & EmployeeIDTextBox.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the handler:

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    'context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    'context.Response.Write("Hello World!")

    Dim EmployeeID As Integer
    If (Not (context.Request.QueryString("EmployeeID")) Is Nothing) Then
        EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString("EmployeeID"))

    Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("No parameter specified")
    End If
    Dim imageData() As Byte = {}
    ' get the image data from the database using the employeeId Querystring
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    ' You can retrieve this also from the database
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageData)

End Sub
```

this is the image control (on Employee.aspx) in which i wanna display the image

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" imageUrl="HttpHandler.ashx?EmployeeID=7" />
```

got a lotta help... seems wasnt enough...

Comment: When you put the full url of `HttpHandler.ashx?EmployeeID=7` directly in the browser, does the image open? If that does not, you should fix that part first.

Comment: it doesnt... if only i knew how to fix it....

Comment: `context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"` will be required. Make sure that type is proper

Comment: the type is proper...

Answer (score 0):

These can be helpful. Scenario is similar and can be achieved for your situation:

[Display image from a datatable in asp:image in code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143323/display-image-from-a-datatable-in-aspimage-in-code-behind)

[Showing an image in listview from datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095376/showing-an-image-in-listview-from-datatable)

Comment: Did you check Telerik binary image control?

Comment: And see this as it is describing the problem you are dealing with: http://aspalliance.com/1322_Displaying_Images_in_ASPNET_Using_HttpHandlers.all

Comment: so now i have to use ajax toolkit??

Comment: No it is independent on Ajax.

Comment: m not really sure... i dont even know how to use it.. i think i will be making things even more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

This is in c# but will help someone.

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string querystring = context.Request.QueryString.ToString();

            try
            {
                if (querystring != null && querystring.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    context.Response.Write("Error");
                    context.Response.Write("No");
                    return;
                }
                string DocCode = querystring;

                DataTable dt = GetDocumentInfo(DocCode); //Get Image From Database. I encapsulated it in other method.Implement it,

                if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                {    
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    context.Response.Write("Error");
                    context.Response.Write("No");
                    return;
                }
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ClearContent();
                context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
                context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);


                context.Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dt.Rows[0]["DocumentFileName"].ToString()));

                context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dt.Rows[0]["DocumentFileName"].ToString()));
                context.Response.Buffer = true;
                context.Response.Charset = "";


                context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["DocumentFile"]);

                context.Response.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write("Error");
                context.Response.Write("No");
                return;
            }
            context.Response.End();
        }
```